# Implement rotation and scall in View

Tags: android

I want to implement single figure rotation and scalling functinality on Frame Layout using bottom right cornor button of Framlayout.following is my code that not working fine.I am triying more than 15 days for it but not find the solution for layout rotation.there are lots of demo available for image rotatin.but i want layout rotation.

```
layout

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fl_main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPhotoEditorClose"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_tv">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhotoEditorImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPhotoEditorPush"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />
```

java

```
    final View imageRootView = getLayout(ViewType.IMAGE);
    final ImageView imageView = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorImage);
    final FrameLayout frmBorder = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.frmBorder);
    final ImageView imgClose = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorClose);
    final ImageView imgPhotoEditorPush = imageRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorPush);


    imgPhotoEditorPush.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        float centerX, centerY, startR, startScale, startX, startY;

        float startAngle;
        float zeroAngle;
        int firstPointX;
        int firstPointY;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {

                // calculate center of image
                centerX = (imageRootView.getLeft() + imageRootView.getRight()) / 2f;
                centerY = (imageRootView.getTop() + imageRootView.getBottom()) / 2f;

                // recalculate coordinates of starting point
                startX = e.getRawX() - imgPhotoEditorPush.getX() + centerX;
                startY = e.getRawY() - imgPhotoEditorPush.getY() + centerY;

                // get starting distance and scale
                startR = (float) Math.hypot(e.getRawX() - startX, e.getRawY() - startY);
                startScale = imageRootView.getScaleX();



                int[] locationOfLayout = new int[2];
                int[] locationOfDrag = new int[2];

                imageRootView.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfLayout);
                imgPhotoEditorPush.getLocationOnScreen(locationOfDrag);

                firstPointX = locationOfLayout[0];
                firstPointY = locationOfLayout[1];

                float secondPointX = e.getRawX();
                float secondPointY = e.getRawY();

                zeroAngle = findRotation(firstPointX, firstPointY, secondPointX, secondPointY); // remember
                // "zero"
                // angle
                startAngle = imageRootView.getRotation(); // remember angle at
                // which layout is
                // rotated at the start

            } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                // calculate new distance
                float newR = (float) Math.hypot(e.getRawX() - startX, e.getRawY() - startY);

                // set new scale
                float newScale = newR / startR * startScale;
                imageRootView.setScaleX(newScale);
                imageRootView.setScaleY(newScale);

                // move handler image
                imgPhotoEditorPush.setX(centerX + imageRootView.getWidth() / 2f * newScale);
                imgPhotoEditorPush.setY(centerY + imageRootView.getHeight() / 2f * newScale);



                imageRootView.setRotation(findRotation(firstPointX, firstPointY, e.getRawX(), e.getRawY()) - zeroAngle + startAngle); // rotate relative to start and zero
                // angle

            }
            else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Please help me.Thaks.